# Google analytics - Event tracking - Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have Google Analytics account on website throught Tag manager.
I would like to track clicks on specific link. 
No idea why it does not work.

```
<li>Registrujte sa na tipli.sk. <strong>Ak využijete tento link: <a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'gymbeam', 'tipli_klik', 'skuska', '0');"  href="https://www.tipli.sk/?p=189672&amp;et=pure&amp;cs=general-sk&amp;utm_source=akosizarobitpeniaze&amp;utm_medium=akosizarobitpeniaze&amp;utm_campaign=akosizarobitpeniaze" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow">https://www.tipli.sk/p/113798</a>
```

It is link right after those two buttons on https://www.akosizarobitpeniaze.sk/gymbeam-zlavovy-kupon/

Analytics is set up as it should be.
Event - gymbeam
Action - tipli_klik
Label - Skuska
Value (eguals to) 0

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GTM, then you should be tracking link clicks with the built-in listeners and not rely on inline code. That said, GTM names its trackers with an internal name so whenever (and for whatever reason) you make calls like `ga('send' ...)`, you need to include the tracker name, for example `ga('gtm0.send', ...)`.